# How to pass block with parameter to a method

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, objective-c-blocks

How to pass typedef void to method

I have a typedef

```
typedef void (^FBLoginHandler)(id <FaceBook>,bool,NSError *error);
```

FBLoginHandler testHandler;

```
^(id<FBLoginHandler>, bool, NSError *)error

[login log:@"AccessToken" handler:^(id<FBLoginHandler>, bool, NSError *)error];
```

Can any one advice me how to pass typedef value to the method

```
 [login log:@"AccessToken" handler:???];
```

Comment: [login log:@"AccessToken" handler:^(id<FBLoginHandler>login, bool success, NSError *)error){

//your method here....use arguments passed inside the block.

}];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[login log:@"AccessToken" handler:^(id<FaceBook> object, bool trueOrFalse, NSError *error){
    // ... do whatever you'd like to do here.
}];
```

or...

```
void ^(handlerBlock)(id<FaceBook>, bool, NSError *) = ^(id<FaceBook> object, bool trueOrFalse, NSError *error) {
    // ... do whatever you'd like to do here
};

[login log:@"AccessToken" handler:handlerBlock];
```

or...

```
[login log:@"AccessToken" handler:nil];
```

Comment: if i pass nil its crashing!

Comment: @kiran, it is probably because they didn't handle the `nil` pointer, or that parameter is not optional. I didn't see the documentation of it. I'd say, generally, you are able to pass `nil` without any problem.